# App Engine NO CACHE JSP

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

I want to disable the cache for a JSP file on my google app engine website.

I have this:

```
<%
        // Set to expire far in the past.
        response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT");

        // Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

        // Set IE extended HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers (use addHeader).
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");

        // Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
%>
```

But the JSP is still in cache. I need to kill the user session and login again in order to reload the JSP code.

How do I disable the cache for a app engine JSP?

Comment: Are you debugging on localhost?

Comment: What do your headers look like from Firebug or Chrome Debugger?  Are you sure the browser is caching them?  I don't have this problem with my JSP pages.  Is it possible they're being cached server-side?

Comment: Firebug is showing the above headers, but I determined it is an issue with Spring MVC, not caching.  I'm updating an entity, then returning a Spring MVC REDIRECT:/some/page.html.  In the handler for /some/page.html, my entity changes are not being picked up.  Still debugging, but this is one of those blasted issues where I just can't seem to understand exactly what is going on and has me flustered beyond reason!

Comment: @Dustin - Are you explicitly putting the object back in the model before the redirect?  Just a thought.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Bit of a hack...  But you could just add a timestamp to the end of the URL for the script block.  <script src="/foo.js?cacheBuster=<%=System.currentTimeMillis()%>" >

Comment: Well, what is odd is I just return a string such as "REDIRECT:/somepage.do" which in turn re-retrieves the object and puts it into the model... However, it seems to retrieve the old values of the object.  To work around, what I did was flatten the object and just return string values in the model and it all works now (ie, instead of returning myUser and accessing in jsp as myUser.name, I return "user_name" in the model.  Guess it may be a GAE caching issue.  At least there's a workaround now.  Thanks for all the ideas. @eSniff -- I tried that as well as putting it on the url, but didn't help.

Comment: Isn't it: response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1); (I'm not an expert, just did some searching, maybe this can help: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread171801.html)

Answer (score 3):

It might at that point be *too late* to change the response headers. They will simply be ignored. You can verify the presence of response headers in a HTTP debugger tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

---

[image]

---

In the JSP, you need to ensure that they are set *before* the response is committed (i.e. all headers are already sent; you cannot send another headers afterwards). I.e. ensure that they are in the very top of the JSP file and that no template text is before that piece of *scriptlet*. Template text may cause a commit of the response. The normal practice, however, is to use a `Filter` for this.

Implement [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) wherein `doFilter()` method look like follows:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache", "no-store", "must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Map this in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `*.jsp` and it ought to work.

#### See also:

- [Making sure a webpage is not cached, across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)