# Webpage doesn't show new entries after saving it. Only appears after refreshing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have a JSP page that shows a list of new entries inserted on the system.

My myApplication.jsp is structured like this:

```
A list of entries in the system
A form with textboxes that submits new entries.
```

When my JSP submits, it calls my servlet class that does:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    String author = checkNull(req.getParameter("author"));
    String service = checkNull(req.getParameter("service"));
    Dao.INSTANCE.add(author, service);
    resp.sendRedirect("/myApplication.jsp");
}
```

My Dao.Add looks like this:

```
public void add(String author,String service) {
    synchronized (this) {
        EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
        Shortly shortly = new Shortly(author, service);
        em.persist(shortly);
        em.close();
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I get redirected back into `myApplication.jsp`, the list does not show the new entry I added.
When I refresh the page, then it shows.

Comment: sounds like a caching problem.

Comment: I added:
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Sat, 01 Dec 2001 00:00:00 GMT">
And still the same issue...
Sometimes I need to refresh twice for the new line to appear.

Comment: still sounds like a caching issue, but perhaps it isn't. if it is a caching problem then perhaps you could manually clear your cache before loading the page. or use a browser add on to clear the cache.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705008/app-engine-no-cache-jsp

Comment: Thanks Moritz, I followed that thread and implemented a Filter, but I still have the problem:
http://i50.tinypic.com/244obv5.png

Might it be related that I'm running it on my localhost? I will try to deploy it later to Google Apps and see if the problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem is around how Google App Engine's High Replication Datastore (HDR) is designed.
HDR can only guarantee [Eventual consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) results.

I have found more info [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency)

The way I proved that's the reason why I'm seeing differences, is by counting the records on the persistence, straight after adding the record.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    String author = checkNull(req.getParameter("author"));
    String service = checkNull(req.getParameter("service"));
    Dao.INSTANCE.add(author, service);
    List shortlys = new ArrayList();
    shortlys = Dao.INSTANCE.getShortlys("default");
    System.out.println("Shortlys count is: " + shortlys.size());
    resp.sendRedirect("/myApplication.jsp");
}
```

Several times, the output didn't increased the count, and sometimes it increased by two (the old record, and the new record added...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE (or even some other browsers), try putting a random number (like a timestamp ) as a parameter in your redirect code piece:

```
 resp.sendRedirect("/myApplication.jsp?t="+timestamp);
```

IE is notorious in such scenarios and due to heavy caching, things don't always work the way expect. This timestamp will indicate the browser not to show a cached page and will always (hopefully) fetch the page from the server afresh.

Comment: Tried your suggestion on IE and Chrome and the same problem happens.
I have a feeling is related to JSP persistence on Google App Engine